# What Is The Best Practice When it Comes To Determining and Counting Odd and Even Numbers in python

Tags: python

For a recent assessment that I have completed in my studies, I have a piece of code that **asks the user for four integers**. Then the program must **count and display the number of odd and even numbers in the entries**. The code is as follows:

```
# xx assignment 02 question 2
a = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
c = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
d = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))
e = 0
o = 0

if a % 2 == 0:
    e = e + 1
else:
    o = o + 1
if b % 2 == 0:
    e = e + 1
else:
    o = o + 1
if c % 2 == 0:
    e = e + 1
else:
    o = o + 1
if d % 2 == 0:
    e = e + 1
else:
    o = o + 1

print("Number of even numbers entered: ", e)
print("Number of odd numbers entered: ", o)
```

The code I have works perfectly, I am not looking for a way to fix the code since it works. I would like to know if the reason for this exercise being marked is justified.

The reason given for the mark is "Rather use a For loop than a series of if-else statements!!!!"

Now, I understand that efficiency is a crucial part of programming, however the mark I got was a negative, although the task's goal was achieved.

Since I just started learning Python, am I missing something here i.e. is there a standard approach that requires you to use a for loop when you want to compare user's input and then perform given tasks to receive the desiredoutput?

Note: I'm not posting this to prove a point to somebody who is just following what they have done for the past few years, as I am learning and I might be wrong and I would like to know why.

Comment: What if you had to test 100 numbers?

Comment: This is not about being new to Python, this means that you don't have yet any understanding of programming. You might consider reading some tutorials about loops and trying again. We won't do that assignment for you, it is important that you understand.

Comment: @LouisSugy OP is not asking us to do the assignment, it has already been marked.

Comment: I mean, it has been marked wrong so he should try to do it again with loops. But of course some answers already give the code

Comment: @LouisSugy as stated before, I am not asking for an assignment to be done for me - I was asking for advice - of which you gave none. I did however receive advice below so I am grateful for that. 

I could edit my question to simply say "I have no understanding of programming please fix this", however everybody except you understands my question.

I am also not really sure why you think a university will make me hand in my assignment "again" to get better marks if I already passed. I assume you have to "try to do it again" quite often though.

Comment: Hey, I upvoted the answer of ShadowRanger which gave good advice about the DRY principle and the Rule of Three. I just wanted to underline that it is more important to read the links that have been given in this answer than the codes that some other answer gave, and try to understand why the assignment was marked as wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code violates a programming principle often referred to as [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) or [the Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)). The idea is to avoid repeated copy-and-paste of code, that makes it harder to spot bugs or subtle changes from line to line, which in turn makes maintenance harder.

You repeated essentially the same code four times, when a loop over `for i in range(4):` that contained the code once would achieve the same effect. It would also make it easier to modify the code. If you need 10 numbers, or 100, or needed the user to tell you how many numbers to expect, changing the loop is trivial, while changing your code would be a royal pain.

Comment: `for i in range(len(4))` would only loop once because` len(4)` is 1

Comment: @RonKalian: I'd already fixed that when you posted. It wouldn't even run once, it would raise a `TypeError`, I just goofed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you recently had a class about loops, so it is fair if the teacher expects you to write code that uses that knowledge. If I were the teacher I'd be annoyed at this code, too.

Good rule of thumb when programming is the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - don't repeat yourself. Your code does exactly the same thing four times. Instead of writing a process and repeating if four times, you made four copies of the code.

By writing your code this way you've shown that you don't understand that principle, and you aren't leveraging the computer's ability to do boilerplate work for you.